# Not able to change timeSeries column name to "current" in grafana v10.2.3

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-alerts, grafana-api

I have this grafana version 10.2.3.

[grafana v10.2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIkVf.png)

In above, I want to change **Last** to **current**, but I am not able to do that, I tried changing the query like this

```
select "value" as current from myTable; 

select last("value") as current from myTable;
```

but nothing is working, can someone please guide me how to change since I am newbie with respect to grafana setup?

Even I tried selecting drop down but there its not possible.

[drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy6o8.png)

Comment: This dropdown shows aggregation functions for graph legend. `Last *` is one of them. You cannot rename it.